# Plot a 3D curve using implicit equations for each coordinate

Tags: graphics3d

Is there a Mathematica command that is a combination of Contour3D and ParametricPlot3D?

It would be something like this:

```
ParaContour3D[f==0, g==0, h==0, {t,0,1}, {x,-3,3}, {y,-3,3}, {z,-3,3}]
```

f, g, h are implicit equations for x, y, and z in terms of t.  For example, we may have `f = t^2 x^2 + t x + 2x - 1`, `g = t^2 y^3 + t y^2 + 2y - 1`, `h = 2t^2 z^3 + t z + 3z - t^2`.  The answer is a curve in space, or maybe several curves.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) to create interpolating functions which you can then plot. Your equations:

```
f[x_, t_] := t^2 x^2 + t x + 2x - 1 == 0
g[y_, t_] := t^2 y^3 + t y^2 + 2y - 1 == 0
h[z_, t_] := 2t^2 z^3 + t z + 3z - t^2 == 0
```

To use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) we need initial conditions:

```
x0 = x /. First @ Solve[f[x, 0], x]
y0 = y /. First @ Solve[g[y, 0], y]
z0 = z /. First @ Solve[h[z, 0], z]
```

> 1/2
>
> 1/2
>
> 0

Now for the [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) call:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    D[f[x[t], t], t], D[g[y[t], t], t], D[h[z[t], t], t],
    x[0]==x0, y[0]==y0, z[0]==z0
    },
    {x[t], y[t], z[t]},
    {t, 0, 1}
];
```

Finally, the requested visualization:

```
ParametricPlot3D[sol, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  It works just as you say.  Now I'll try it on the more complicated real examples I really want.

Comment: Having now read about NDSolveValue, which I never knew about before, I see your method creates differential equations and solves those.  This seems rather roundabout.  Is there a more direct method?  (My original problem does not involve differential equations.)

Answer (score 0):

```
f = t^2 x^2 + t x + 2 x - 1;
g = t^2 y^3 + t y^2 + 2 y - 1;
h = 2 t^2 z^3 + t z + 3 z - t^2;

TraditionalForm /@ (sol[t_] = {x, y, z} /. 
      Solve[{f == 0, g == 0, h == 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals] // 
     ToRadicals // FullSimplify[#, Element[t, Reals]] &)
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Row[ParametricPlot3D[
     #, {t, -tmax, tmax},
     PlotRange -> {{-50, 10}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}},
     PlotPoints -> 100,
     PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4],
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
     ImageSize -> 324,
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t},
       Blend[{Red, Green}, t]]] & /@ sol[t]],
 {{tmax, 50, Subscript["t", max]}, 5, 60, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the real examples will be of degree > 4, in part.

Comment: @rfermat - for higher degree or transcendental expressions, don't use [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) and just use the [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects. You could also just use the `Root` objects in this case.